# Método de ordenação de um vetor de nomes

Tags: java, classificação

Estou tentando ordenar um vetor de nomes com este método, mais quando tem letra minuscula e acentuo os nomes vão para o fim da lista, alguém sabe um método que ordene considerando letras maiúsculas , minusculas , com acentuação ?

```
String nomes[] = { "Ana","aa","B" };
for (int i = 0; i < nomes.length - 1; ++i)  
    for (int j = i + 1; j < nomes.length; ++j)  
        if (nomes[i].compareTo(nomes[j]) > 0) {  
            String temp = nomes[i];  
            nomes[i] = nomes[j];  
            nomes[j] = temp;  
        }
```

Comment: Para ignorar as letras maiúsculas existe o `compareToIgnoreCase`.

Comment: e a acentuação você sabe?

Comment: Em JAVA se usares um ArrayList consegues fazer a ordenação com o compareTo.
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm

Comment: você pode usar o próprio método `sort()` do vetor pra fazer isso.

Comment: Ilgner o StackOveflow não é como os demais fóruns. Aqui não se marcam as questões como respondidas.

Comment: Para além disso, fez a pergunta para vetor de nomes, e a resposta certa é com vetor de nomes, se quiser saber com ArrayList seria melhor criar uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em java você pode utilizar um objeto do tipo `Collator` para fazer a ordenação.
Segue um exemplo de uso:

```
Collator brCollator = Collator.getInstance(new Locale("pt","BR"));
public static void sortStrings(Collator collator, String[] words) {
String tmp;
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < words.length; j++) { 
        if (collator.compare(words[i], words[j]) > 0) {
            tmp = words[i];
            words[i] = words[j];
            words[j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

Dessa maneira ele vai ordenar de acordo com nosso português.

Comment: Tentei passar a usar com o meu arraylist 
public static ArrayList<Pessoa> ordena(Collator collator, ArrayList<Pessoa> contatos) {
  Pessoa tmp;
  for (int i = 0; i < contatos.size(); i++) {
      for (int j = i + 1; j < contatos.size(); j++) {
       
          if (collator.compare(contatos.get(i).nome, contatos.get(j).nome) > 0) {
           tmp=new Pessoa();
              tmp = contatos.get(i);
              contatos.set(i, contatos.get(i));
              contatos.set(j, tmp);
          }
      }
  }
  return contatos;
 }
mais na hora de ordenar ele só ta pegando um contato, consegue ver pq?

Comment: Ainda está com problema? Chegando na faculdade eu do uma olhada

Comment: Estou tentando ver aonde eu errei , este metodo ai funciona perfeitamente , mais quando eu alterei para aceitar o meu Arraylist de Pessoa ele ta preenchendo tudo só com um nome

Comment: Já achei aonde eu errei kk , troquei um j por i ai tava pegando sempre o mesmo nome e colocando no lugar do outro , vlw ajudou muito

Comment: Muito bem, valeu :D

Comment: @IIgner, quando se utiliza `ArrayList` o jeito mais facil e eficiente é utilizando a função `sort(List<T> list)` da classe Collections... desta forma: `Collections.sort(listaAOrdenar);`

Comment: sim, até coloquei no comentário da sua pergunta, da uma olhada la :D